# AngularJS confirm before route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to listen for route changes AND onwindowunload both to confirm page leave without saving changes?

Use cases:

- User clicks [Back](/foo)
- User presses back button in browser
- User types in a different URL

If the user clicks 'cancel' stop the page / route change.

I've seen a few different examples but none worked quite right.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Aq8uYg

In the demo, if you change the value of input, you will be noticed when trying to go back.

Listen to `$locationChangeStart` and use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the location change if changes not confirmed.

This method has one advantage over `$route.reload()`: current controller and models will not be re-instantiated. thus all of your variables are kept the same as user click the "Back" button.

Comment: What if i do something like: `$location.path('config/' + $routeParams.id);` will this still work?

Comment: @amcdnl I didn't try, but you can test it by changing anchor tag's `herf` to `ng-click` and try.

Comment: this didn't work for my case when user clicks on anchor with ui-sref directive. In that case, locationChangeStart was triggered after state change.

Answer (score 12):

You'll find the `$locationChangeStart` is an event you can listen for to detect for a route change.

Try something like

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
  /* do some verification */
});
```

`$route.reload()` will prevent the route change from going through.

The distinction between user clicking back or changing the url etc will not make a difference. As browsers don't reload any resources when you alter the url past the `#` it's all still contained in your angular logic. This means all these methods should trigger the `$locationChangeStart` event.

@Jon pointed out that the `$route` service will definitely be of use to you. the `.reload()` method will prevent the route change from completing but there is much more you can do with the `$route` service if you look into it - see [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route).

Comment: Be sure to check out [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route) too.. There are some events you may wish to utilize.

Comment: @LawerenceJones Few notes:  $route.reload() does not stop the page change.  This does not work when typing in a different url into the browser, I suppose I would need to do an `onunload` too.

Comment: Are you certain you are only editing the part of the url past the `#`? I've testing it in chrome now and it's picking it up on that event. I should clarify that the `$route.reload` will only work to reload the current route, therefore preventing the route change in the first place.

Comment: Also, just FYI - I found that $routeChangeStart is not cancellable, +1 for $locationChangeStart

Answer (score 4):

I would just maintain a property on your $rootScope like `hasUnsavedEdits`.

```
function confirmLeavePage(e) {
  var confirmed;
  if ($rootScope.hasUnsavedEdits) {
    confirmed = $window.confirm("You have unsaved edits. Do you wish to leave?");
    if (e && !confirmed) { 
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}

$window.addEventListener('beforeunload', confirmLeavePage);

$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", confirmLeavePage);
```

You might have to tweak the code a bit to handle both conditions. See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lijUGfIuyFwtSidqKpYt?p=preview) for details.

Comment: This does not prevent the page change either.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Does `confirmLeavePage` fire? Does $window.confirm pop up a message?

Answer (score 4):

This is also nice link
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs-controllers

```
function init() {

    //initialize data here..
    //Make sure they're warned if they made a change but didn't save it
    //Call to $on returns a "deregistration" function that can be called to
    //remove the listener (see routeChange() for an example of using it)
    onRouteChangeOff = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', routeChange);
}

function routeChange(event, newUrl) {
    //Navigate to newUrl if the form isn't dirty
    if (!$scope.editForm.$dirty) return;

    var modalOptions = {
        closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
        actionButtonText: 'Ignore Changes',
        headerText: 'Unsaved Changes',
        bodyText: 'You have unsaved changes. Leave the page?'
    };

    modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
        if (result === 'ok') {
            onRouteChangeOff(); //Stop listening for location changes
            $location.path(newUrl); //Go to page they're interested in
        }
    });

    //prevent navigation by default since we'll handle it
    //once the user selects a dialog option
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following service that incorporates information given in the other answers (CoffeeScript, see [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/APz0s4uLD0vQ23IqIHMH/preview) ):

```
angular.module('myModule').service 'ChangeLossPreventer', ($rootScope, $q, $state) ->

  confirmationMessage = null

  service =
    prevent: (message = 'Changed data will be lost. Continue?') ->
      confirmationMessage = message

    prompt: ->
      confirmation = if confirmationMessage then confirm(confirmationMessage) else yes
      if not confirmation
        $q.reject()
      else
        $q.when(confirmation).then ->
          service.cancel()

    cancel: ->
      confirmationMessage = null

  $rootScope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (event, newState, newStateParams) ->
    if confirmationMessage
      event.preventDefault()
      service.prompt().then ->
        $state.go(newState, newStateParams)

  window.onbeforeunload = ->
    confirmationMessage

  service
```

It is based on angular-ui-router (usage of the `$state` service). When your website enters the state in which data may be lost, you need to call

```
ChangeLossPreventer.prevent("Optional warning message.");
```

When it exists this state (i.e. user saves the data), you need to call:

```
ChangeLossPreventer.cancel()
```

By default, warning will appear on state change or page close (i.e. refresh or going to another website). You may also need to verify if it is safe to execute another actions (i.e. do not logout with XHR if there are unsaved changes):

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    // confirmation will pop up only if there are unsaved changes
    ChangeLossPreventer.prompt().then(function(){
       // logout after confirmation
    });
};
```

I have created a [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/APz0s4uLD0vQ23IqIHMH/preview) that simulates it.

1. Click the text on home page (page will enter "unsafe" state).
2. Try clicking other links or refreshing the page - warning should appear.
3. After "saving" the field, page leaves unsafe state and everything works as before.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular ES6 Users

```
export default class myRouteController {

  constructor($scope, $window) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$window = $window;

    this.$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (evt) => {
      if(this.form.$dirty && !$window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  }
}
```