# clicking back button in angularjs multiple alert shows 1 after other

Tags: angularjs

I am using:

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", confirmLeavePage);
function confirmLeavePage(e) {
      var confirmed;
      confirmed = $window.confirm('contents are not saved');
      if (e && !confirmed) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

i got this from
[[AngularJS confirm before route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847784/angularjs-confirm-before-route-change])

working fine for me, only problem, i am getting multile alert boxes.
can any1 help?

Comment: Help with what? We don't know what your goals are. If you only want that on one route, check which route you are on

Comment: My initial url:  https://localhost:8443/ecoR/app/?code=5b7d92da-16dd-4ce0-9c94-bc962fd7a1e7#/home  .... on clicking back button my url becomes https://localhost:8443/ecoR/app/?code=5b7d92da-16dd-4ce0-9c94-bc962fd7a1e7#/ with confirm box, on clicking ok... again confirm box comes... i want to ignore 2nd confirm box.

Comment: Ahh ... how do you expect us to access your localhost?