# Event not waiting the $mdDialog confirmation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angular-material

I want the behaviour of a $mdDialog to be like confirm() when called inside a $locationchangestart.
The $mdDialog does not wait for the user input before resuming the location change.

```
$rootScope.showConfirm = function (ev) {
        // Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('Tem certeza que deseja sair?')
            .textContent('Informações não salvas serão perdidas"')
            .targetEvent(ev)
            .ok('Sim')
            .cancel('Não');

        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            $rootScope.status = true;
        }, function () {
            $rootScope.status = false;
        });
    };


 $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        $rootScope.showConfirm(event);

        if($rootScope.status == false){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the hook `$locationChangeStart` as follows and see if it works:

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        if(!$rootScope.showConfirm(event)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Modify the showConfirm to return true/false based on user response as follows:

```
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
  return true;
}, function () {
  return false;
});
```

There is a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20849163/5346095). Hope that helps as well.

Comment: Does not work. The $mdDialog never stops the location change from happening.

Comment: just a suggestion: you could call $rootScope.showConfirm to show Modal on click of button/link where you want to change route. Inside $rootScope.showConfirm on click of ok do $location.path() stuff. This way you wont have to worry about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is not the best and has a bad code smell, but it does work. I am still looking for a better answer to the problem and if you do come across one, please let me know.

```
var isLeaving = false;

$scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    if ($scope.form.$dirty && !isLeaving) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dialog = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .parent(angular.element(document.body))
            .clickOutsideToClose(false)
            .title('Exit Form')
            .textContent('Are you sure you want to exit?')
            .ariaLabel('Exit Form')
            .ok('Yes')
            .cancel('No');

        $mdDialog.show(dialog).then(function () {
            //do something here...
            isLeaving = true;
            $location.path(next.$$route.originalPath)
        }, function () {
            //do something here...
            isLeaving = false;
        });
    }
});
```